# How can i use the variable %TIME:~0,2% in a batch file so that times with a leading space do not cause errors?

Tags: datetime, batch-file, formatting

I am trying to run a batch file, which runs an XSLT transformation against an XML file and writes out a second XML file.

This XML filename is determined by the following line in the batch file:

```
 ICS_%DATE:~-4%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_DATA.xml
```

When the time has a leading space (that is, any time before 10:00 am), the variable `%TIME:~3,2%` returns a result with a leading space, which causes the filename to be truncated. The result file is empty.

If I run the batch after 10:00am, everything works fine. How can I generate a value similar to `%TIME:~3,2%`that works before 10:00am?

Comment: Couldn't you use a variable and then have an `IF %TIME% < 10` add a 0 to the front (or remove if you need to)?  If not you could try adding something before the time to force it to stay there.

Comment: It actually appears, after further testing, that a space is being added by the `%TIME:~0,2%` expression, and this is what is causing the error. This makes a lot more sense, because the value for the month is 05 right now, and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a variable for the hour value as follows solves the problem for me:
     `FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a IN ("%TIME:~0,2%") DO SET hour=%%a`

Comment: Can you mark this as Accepted if you've solved your problem?  I'm still confused as to whether your question has been answered correctly or not.

Comment: This doesn't do anything with/for/against  leading zeros.

Comment: It wasn't the leading zeroes. It was leading spaces. This does solve my problem, but I cannot accept it as an answer for two days.

Comment: In that case, all you needed to to was to enclose the filename in double-quotes.

Comment: True, that would have prevented the error, but would not have resulted in the correct filename.

Comment: This is not the right answer for leading zeros. It might solve your issue, but this was not the question. Nobody here has a crystal ball to see, you mean "space" if you ask "zero". You should delete your question **or** (much better) accept one of the other answers.

Comment: You're right, of course. Since it was my question, and my problem, and the problem is solved, I modified the question to reflect the true nature of the issue I was seeing. Also, I mentioned the leading space in a comment to the original question. I apologize for being unclear.

Answer (score 17):

This will solve the space in the name issue, and replace it with a zero so it sorts correctly in a list.

```
set name=ICS_%DATE:~-4%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_DATA.xml
set name=%name: =0%
```

Comment: This is best solution I guess. I only wonder is it possible to rewrite it somehow in one-line without assigning value to variable? For example, I simply need to `echo %time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%` and replace spaces with 0.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one ?

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=., " %%i IN ('DATE /t') DO SET cpdate=%%k_%%j_%%i
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:"  %%b IN ('TIME /T') DO SET cptime=%%b_%%c

set filename=blabla_%cpdate%_%cptime%_%TIME:~-5,2%.xml

echo %filename%
```

The locale here is german, so you might have to adjust the order in "set cpdate..." for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The result of your suggestion is:`blabla__05/06/2013_Mon_07_09 AM_55.xml`, which is not what is desired. The desired format of the filename is `blabla_2013_05_06_07_09_DATA.xml`.

Comment: ok, in germany we separate the numbers in the date with a "." character. For me it produces blabla_2013_05_06_21_19_59.xml  Try using `FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/., " %%i IN ('DATE /t') DO SET cpdate=%%k_%%j_%%i` in the 2nd line. Post the output of `date /t` and `time /t` if it still does not work for you. I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 3):

(This is an old question but this answer could be of help for somebody else.)

Using `%time: =%` gets rid of the spaces in the time variable.
Example:

```
C:\>echo %time%
 04:00:00,00

C:\>echo %time: =%
04:00:00,00
```

You could save the time variable to another using this method and then work from that one:

```
set "tim2=%time: =%"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set time=%time:~0,5%
if "%time:~0,1%" == " " set time=0%time:~1,5%
echo %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
```

my time is: 9:48:27,00

I add a zero if it is missing and

echo %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%  is now 0948

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple trick to do this:

```
set h=1%TIME:~0,2%
set /a h=%h%-100
```

Answer (score 0):

REM This .bat script gives you a parameter timetext with a zero instead of a space

```
@echo off

set timetext=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
echo TIME BEFORE WITH SPACE %timetext%

set digit1=%time:~0,1%

if "%digit1%"==" " set digit1=0

set timetext=%digit1%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%
echo TIME AFTER WITH ZERO.. %timetext%

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe more helpful in Dos Batch ~~ try this

```
if "%time:~0,1%" == " " (set dtstamp=0%time:~1,1%) ELSE set dtstamp=%time:~0,2%
echo dtstamp=%date:~6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%dtstamp%%time:~3,2%
```